# python3 virtualenv no such file or directory

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to follow this guide http://thecodeship.com/deployment/deploy-django-apache-virtualenv-and-mod_wsgi/ to set up virtual env on apache. I run into problems at the last stage with the index.wsgi. Here is the content of my index.wsgi:

```
import os
import sys
import site

# Add the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
site.addsitedir('~/.virtualenvs/splinter/lib/python3.2/site-packages')

# Add the app's directory to the PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append('/var/www/splinter')
sys.path.append('/var/www/splinter/splinter')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'splinter.settings'

# Activate your virtual env
activate_env=os.path.expanduser("~/.virtualenvs/splinter/bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

The error logs states:

```
No such file or directory: '/var/www/.virtualenvs/splinter/bin/activate_this.py'
```

It's adding 'var/www/' to the front of the path, so I tried removing the os.path.expanduser and even though now the path is correct, and the file definately exists, I still get the same error:

```
No such file or directory: '~/.virtualenvs/splinter/bin/activate_this.py'
```

Please help me fix this, I feel so close!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possibility is to use *your* username to expanduser:

```
activate_env = os.path.expanduser(
    "~chris/.virtualenvs/splinter/bin/activate_this.py")
```

Comment: Thanks, that solves that problem. But now it seems it's using python 2.7 instead of 3.2. Further into the rabbit hole I go...

Comment: Ah indeed. Actually you should force the WSGI server to use `/home/whatever/chris/.virtualenvs/splinter/bin/python` as **the** interpreter.

Comment: Where do I set this exactly? Please see my other question related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28926170/mkvirtualenv-python3-2-permission-denied

Comment: What is your operating system. The **mod_wsgi** must be built for your exact python version...

Comment: Ubuntu. I installed mod_wsgi from source code, but I'm not sure if it's being used instead of the original version I installed. I'm pretty new to all this as I'm sure you can tell....

Comment: which version of ubuntu. you should be using mod_wsgi of ubuntu isntead, same for Python

Comment: version 12.04.3. Think I might start fresh another day, my brain a bit fried now...

Comment: If possible, upgrade to 14.04 which has Python 3.3, 3.4 natively.