# mkvirtualenv python3.2 permission denied

Tags: python, django

Trying to create a virtualenv using the command:

```
mkvirtualenv -p /usr/local/lib/python3.2 splinter
```

Gives me the response:

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/lib/python3.2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 784, in main
    popen = subprocess.Popen([interpreter, file] + sys.argv[1:], env=env)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/subprocess.py", line 745, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/subprocess.py", line 1361, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

How oh how can I start a virtualenv using python3.2?

Comment: If i run the command without specifying the python version it works fine, but it always runs 2.7. Is there another place I should be setting the python version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to supply the path to the path to the Python *interpreter* with `-p`, not the `lib` directory.

Because you're passing that directory, virtualenv is trying to execute it, and therefore you get `Permission denied`. So use the path to the `python` executable in the `bin` directory instead (use `which python3.2` to find out if you don't know the location).

This should work, assuming your Python 3.2 interpreter can be found at `/usr/local/bin/python3.2`:

```
mkvirtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3.2 splinter
```

Comment: Use `which python3.2` to find out the location to the interpreter executable then.

Comment: Aha yes it's in /usr/bin/python3.2. Thanks